# cdk-drop is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, drag, angular7

I'm using the new feature of Angular 7 "Drag and Drop" I followed all the steps on the officiel docs : ***https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview***

but I'am getting this error : 
**

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'cdk-drop' is not a known
>   element:
>   1. If 'cdk-drop' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'cdk-drop' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**

here is my app.component.html code :

```
<cdk-drop cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}} 
  </div>
</cdk-drop>
```

here is my app.component.ts code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    movies = [
    'Episode I - The Phantom Menace',
    'Episode II - Attack of the Clones',
    'Episode III - Revenge of the Sith',
    'Episode IV - A New Hope',
    'Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
    'Episode VI - Return of the Jedi',
    'Episode VII - The Force Awakens',
    'Episode VIII - The Last Jedi'
    ];

    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    }
}
```

NB : I'm using => Angular: 7.1.2
& if I change the **cdk-drop** html element by a **div** also not working :(

Comment: What is in your NgModule file ?

Comment: NgModule file ? I don't have a file with this name

Comment: Check my answer, seems you forget that part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `app.module.ts` you should

```
import {DragDropModule} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
```

and then in the `imports` array (within `@NgModule` decorator) of the same file add `DragDropModule`.

---

Also there is nothing exported in `@angular/material` as `cdk-drop` change your html part to :

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I added the **DragDropModule** to the imports in my **app.modules.ts** file also I imported the **DragDropModule** in my **app.component.ts** file

Comment: @SaidSOUALHI Import it in `app.module.ts` not `app.component.ts`

Comment: There is TWO imports, the import in the head of the file and the imports array within @NgModule decorator. You should make both of them.

Comment: Yes I do both of them on the head of the file and inside @NgModule in imports

Comment: @SaidSOUALHI cut ur server and rerun.

Comment: The same error still, here is my app on github : 
https://github.com/saidsoualhi/todolistapp

Comment: @SaidSOUALHI am using my phone  once getting home i'll poke u. 30 mn

Comment: @SaidSOUALHI welcome, your problem is that there's nothing exported as `cdk-drop`, check my updated answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The doc you read must be outdated.  I followed a blog post and experienced the same problem.

Element `<cdk-drop>` is not there anymore.  The directive cdkDropList is used instead.

Make sure to check the latest doc first when strange errors happen.

As of today, this example works https://stackblitz.com/angular/moyomqpeprev?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.html